# Getting error in java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, compiler-errors

I am getting this error in the statement below:

```
type List does not take parameters
```

I am using this in my document listener class to validate all my text fields and once they are validated,enable the submit button.  The above statement is used to store all the text field documents in a list so that they can be validated combined.

```
List<Document> documents =new ArrayList<Document>();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this statement, assuming you haven't created your own List class that hides java.util.List

Comment: You are using `import java.awt.List;`. Use `import java.util.List;` instead.

Comment: Didn't see you comment while replying. Sorry about that ^^

Comment: No i haven't created a List class that hides java.util.List.

Comment: The error is still there.Any solutions??

Comment: ok guys i have sorted the problem

Comment: it was because i was using import java.awt.*; and javax.swing.*;

Comment: so it was showing ambiguity

Comment: now i have corrected it

Comment: thank u everyone for the help